# How to get message from org.springframework.context.MessageSource manually?

Tags: java, spring, localization

I am doing some validation stuff in `javax.servlet.Filter` and I would like to get message from message source bean, message "Client id must not be empty" in this example.

```
if (StringUtils.isEmpty(clientId)) {
    HttpResponseWriter.throwBadRequest(
            response,
            new BadRequestResponseMessage("Client id must not be empty")
    );
}
```

I would like to get message from message source to avoid duplicating messages and `l10n`.

**Is it possible and if so, how?**

Answer (score 0):

Injecting `messageSource` and then calling `messageSource.getMessage(messageKey, args, LocaleContextHolder.getLocale())` works for me.

In fact, in a couple of projects, I've put this it in a static utility function, injecting `messageSource` into a static variable. See the `getMessage` method in [LemonUtil](https://github.com/naturalprogrammer/spring-lemon/blob/master/src/main/java/com/naturalprogrammer/spring/lemon/util/LemonUtil.java) of Spring Lemon for a concrete example.